# how to display a quick message in Blackberry like Android's Toast?

Tags: android, user-interface, blackberry

I want to draw some message box on screen that will can not get focus and be unobtrusive.

Just like Android's Toast.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to display a rounded rectangle with text which disappears by itself like in this Android screenshot:

[image]

then just call [Status.show()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Status.html) on Blackberry:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is

[void net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Status.show(String message)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Status.html)

Shows a status screen for two seconds. 
Invoke this method to show a status screen to the user for two seconds. This method blocks until the user dismisses this screen, or until the two seconds pass. 
This method shows a screen using the predefined icon Bitmap.INFORMATION.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Looks like there is no such similar BB API as Android's Toast.</strike>

However just an idea - you could try to put a `LabelField` into `MainScreen.setStatus(Field status)` and remove it after some delay.

See what `Alexander Farber` and `endevour` answered.

Answer (score 2):

The [EyelidFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/container/EyelidFieldManager.html) allows you to implement something similar to a toast.